# NLTK PCFG ' AttributeError: 'PCFG' object has no attribute 'rules''

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I'm working on the Dynamic Programming - CYK algorithm on Probabilistic Context Free Grammar for finding the most probable parse tree.

I'm using NLTK's Treebank to induce PCFG. But, I'm unable to iterate through or extract individual rules in a PCFG Grammar.

```
productions =[]

for item in treebank.fileids()[:300]:
  for tree in treebank.parsed_sents(item):
    tree.chomsky_normal_form(horzMarkov = 2)
    productions += tree.productions()

S = Nonterminal('S')
grammar = induce_pcfg(S, productions)
print(grammar)

grammar.rules()
```

The above code gives me error in  `grammar.rules()` saying:

```
 'PCFG' object has no attribute 'rules'
```

But, the NLTK documentation did show a function `.rules()` for the PCFG Object.

Could someone please help me with resolving this error?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), Currently your code is incomplete and makes it difficult to help.

Comment: I got it resolved ! Thanks . I had to use .productions()